# How to align correctly this SVG inside the Victory Scatter Graph

Tags: victory-charts

I have a problem with aligning the SVG component DataPointCircle inside the Victory Scatter Graph.

My main problem is not how it looks but how it acts.

the tooltip and the VictoryVoronoiContainer is acting weird when hovered over the data circles.

When the data circle is hovered it sometimes shows the tooltip sometimes not!, this is more clear on the last data point.

Since I had to do this x={x - 10} y={y - 10} to properly align the data points, I thought that maybe it is causing a distortion.

I need the tooltip and VictoryVoronoiContainer to act normal. I'm 100% if it is an aligning problem or if I need to do something else, suggestions would be lovely!.

Thanks in advance.

Here is a SandBox 
https://codesandbox.io/s/YED2ql2mK

Answer (score 0):

The answer was posted in github:

> Yes, that [manually add offset props x={x - 10} y={y - 10}] would definitely be causing the issue. VictoryVoronoiContainer calculates the positions of all of your data points. If you move the points around manually, the triggers will no longer match up. I don't think this is something I can fix at the library level. It might be better to add the tooltips directly to VictoryScatter so that they will be attached to your custom point components regardless of how you you manually position them

https://github.com/FormidableLabs/victory/issues/695